# JavaFXPorts 8.60.7 app crash when traying type into TextField

Tags: mobile, javafx, javafxports, gluon, gluon-mobile

I have an issue with latest JavaFXPorts 8.60.7 when I type any char from keyboard to TextField, app will crash. I'm using android 5.0.1. Earlier my app was developed on JavaFXPorts 8.60.6 and there my app was working, I could in 8.60.6, type a characters into TextField.

I receive in logcat this error:

```
04-15 21:56:22.066 10732-10769/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: JavaFX Application Thread
Process: pl.plf.myapp, PID: 10732
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method dispatchKeyEvent(II[CI)V in class Lcom/sun/glass/ui/monocle/AndroidInputDeviceRegistry; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.AndroidInputDeviceRegistry' appears in /data/app/pl.plf.myapp-1/base.apk)
        at javafxports.android.KeyEventProcessor$1.run(KeyEventProcessor.java:53)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$155(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.access$lambda$18(PlatformImpl.java)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$19.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:52)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$156(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.access$lambda$5(PlatformImpl.java)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$6.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.runLoop(RunnableProcessor.java:92)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.run(RunnableProcessor.java:51)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

And this is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7
version = '1.0'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.8'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
     compile project(":ApiCore")
     compile project(":Validation")
     compile project(":PLFModel")
     compile 'org.javafxports:jfxdvk:8.60.7'

     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
     runtime fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

mainClassName = 'pl.plf.myapp.MainApp'

jfxmobile {
    android {
        javafxportsVersion = '8.60.7'
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        androidSdk = '/home/user/Android/Sdk'
        packagingOptions { 
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
    dexOptions {   
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }
    }
}
```

Thank's for any help.

Comment: Thanks for reporting. An internal issue has been filed.

Comment: Thank's for replay. Can you tell me where I can track this issue. And fix for it will land to 8.60.6 version?

Comment: You can check any change made at the javafxports repository [here](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/8u-dev-rt). Changes won't be back ported to previous versions. Hopefully you will be able to use 8.60.8 with this issue solved.